# js click delegate determine if not the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a delegated click event on '#id'.

However, I want to know have a function when the event.target is not '#id'

```
$(document).on('click', '#id', handler)

function handle(event){
   el.show();

 // I want to do if current click is not '#id', el.hide();

}
```

I understand register a event on document can do this, but I dont want to register a event like below. Is there another way I can determine if target is not the element ??

```
$(document).on('click', handler)

function handle(event){
   $(event.target).is(el)
   ?  el.show()
   :  el.hide();    
}
```

Comment: What's the use-case? A dropdown menu?

Comment: no, just show or hide the element

Comment: If you want to catch clicks on something that's not `#id`, setting a delegate on `document` is the only (practical) way. But without knowing what your use-case is, it will be hard to help you.

Comment: Thank you very much. The reason I am asking this is because if register a click on document, I will like lose right click function on Firefox, but not on Chrome and IE

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I completely understand the question, but:

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if ($(e.currentTarget).is('#div')) {
        // this is the target div
    }
});
```

Comment: So why is this not suitable for your use case?

Comment: The reason I am asking this is because if register a click on document, I will like lose right click function on Firefox, but not on Chrome and IE

Comment: The right click will become wired after I assigned the event, I dont know why

Comment: I just registered the click event on this document (this page right now), and I'm still able to use right click in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

Comment: thank you for helping, all will work fine if I stop that simple click function on document on Firefox. I dont know why, actually Firefox can not use scroll() too, u need to on('scroll')....

Comment: ^ Sure it can. Are you calling `scroll` on `window` or `document`? Is there any error/warning output in FF when you try to right click or do anything after binding `click` to `document`?

Comment: What other events have you bound in your javascript? If you'd like, message me here on SO and I'll try to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

try using :

```
document.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
  if ($(e.currentTarget).is(el)) {
    // do something
  }
});
```